# How to: Getting SSL to work on Wordpress without 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

The problem is as follows:

I want to install a SSL certificate on my WP e-commerce WordPress website. I already installed the SSL via DirectAdmin. Besides many small tryouts, I have tried *2 main methods*:

1. Installed "Wordpress SSL" and forced the Admin panel into SSL encryption.> Via this method I was blocked out of the Admin panel and got a 404 error immediately after. When trying to access /wp-admin panel.
2. Transfer all files in Public_HTML to Private_HTML and changed the website url in the WP admin panel from http to https://.> Via this method I can succesfully log in into the /wp-admin/ panel with SSL (https) ecryption. + all the pages worked when adding https:// to the URL. After adding a redirect via .HTACCESS I could also access all pages without adding https:// (thus via standard http://) in front of the url. Only problem was, all the images were gone.

Question. How can I get SSL to work (preferably only the admin panel) without loosing all images?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as #1 on your list (404 errors when trying to access any URL on my website via https) and the solution for me was to add these lines to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`, which is my SSL-enabled website's configuration file:

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

Of course, this assumes `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`. Change accordingly if is this is different in your setup.

The thing is that Wordpress uses .htaccess rules to process the URLs and for them to work, `AllowOverride All` needs to be in the server's configuration file.

In my situation, the configuration for the non-SSL and SSL-enabled variants were in a separate files. The non-SSL configuration had `AllowOverride All` all along, and so everything was working fine. Once I had enabled the SSL, the other configuration file came into play and didn't have the required `AllowOverride All` setting.